# Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients matrix and condition for non-vanishing elements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In QM, is it true generally when considering addition of angular momenta that $m = m_1 + m_2$ or is this the case only when considering elements of the matrix of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients i.e. $\langle j_1j_2; m_1 m_2 | j_1 j_2; jm \rangle$ which can be shown to vanish unless $m = m_1 + m_2$?

For example when considering the case where we have a single spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle with say $j_{1} = l$, $m_{1} = m_{l}$, $j_{2} = s = \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_{2} = m_{s} =  \frac{1}{2}$. Is it the case here that we immediately consider $m = m_{l} + m_{s}$ where $m$ is an eigenvalue of the common eigenstate $|j_1j_2; jm \rangle$ of $\hat{J}^2$ and $J_{z}$? What about the case where we consider two particles?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not particularly clear, but if what you're asking is

> is it possible to find an uncoupled state $|j_1j_2;m_1m_2⟩$ and a coupled state $|j_1j_2;jm⟩$ such that $m\neq m_1+m_2$?

then the answer is obviously **yes**, it is plenty possible to find such combinations - there's a sea around you in any sum-of-angular-momenta calculation, and you just need to look around to find them.

Why don't we normally consider these pairs of states? Because, as you note, $|j_1j_2;m_1m_2⟩$ can only contribute to $|j_1j_2;jm⟩$ whenever $m=m_1+m_2$ (i.e. if the condition is false, its amplitude -- the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient -- vanishes, and the state does not contribute), and therefore we drop those states from consideration at the first time it becomes convenient. Which is usually the very first step in the calculation.